# How to capture all output from a shell script execution to a log file

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script `worker.sh` which in turn calls various python scripts `Script1.py`, `Script2.py` etc like this `python3 Script2.py > shell.log`. There are also various print statements within the shell script and the python script to know what is happening and which statement is being executed.

```
echo "Begin execution of Python Script" > shell.log
python3 Script2.py > shell.log
echo "End of execution" > shell.log
```

Is this the normal approach to log everything happening including the errors in both shell and python scripts or is there a better way of doing this instead of piping each `echo` statement to log file. I wanted to capture everything happening(errors as well) since the execution of shell script, including any `echo` statements in shell and `print` statements in python script.

Edit: The main shell script will be called via Apache NiFi.

Answer (score 1):

What if you remove all '>'s from your script, and then rather logged the output of the whole script to shell.log?

worker.sh:

```
echo "Begin execution of Python Script"
python3 script.py
echo "End of execution"
```

Run it

`sh worker.sh > shell.log`

Which would then write

```
Begin execution of Python Script
Hello from Python!
End of execution
```

in shell.log.

Answer (score 0):

try append '>>' instead of  overwrite '>'

```
echo "Begin execution of Python Script" >> shell.log
python3 Script2.py >> shell.log
echo "End of execution" >> shell.log
```